# Ubuntu - Unable to login to root via fresh install

Tags: ubuntu

I know my password, I used the same one for root as my personal user.  This is my 2nd time reinstalling the OS because it won't let me login as root.  Even when I login as my own user and then "su root" it won't take my password.

Am I missing something that needs to be setup about the root user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you are a hardcore redhat fan.root user is normally disabled in ubuntu due to security reasons. Look at the sudo concept
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

You can do one thing to make root user active

type

```
$sudo passwd root
```

It will prompt you for password. Enter your new password
then you can try

```
$ su
```

this will drop you directly to the root shell

Comment: What does Red Hat have to do with the `root` user?

Comment: Because RH doesn't disable the root user logins, Ubuntu does.

Comment: @Mistiry: Almost **all** Unix distributions (several hundreds of Linux distros, most BSDs, Minix) come with `root` **enabled**. RedHat is not special in any way.

Comment: I didn't realize it was pretty standard on ubuntu.... thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @grawity: I never said "RedHat is the ONLY one", but it is well known that Red Hat and RH-based distros do not explicitly disallow root logins, Ubuntu does. The original answerer mentioned Red Hat, and my original comment was @joschi's comment asking a question specifically about Red Hat, hence my answer.